# Allow the user to select a folder without iclude a filemanager in the app

Tags: android, intentfilter

I need to allow the user to choose a folder getting the path of the chosen folder.

I have seen in another question that has been suggested to include a file manager in the app to achieve this,
Seems absurd that a developer is forced to include a bunch of redundant code to add an own file manager to every app for a common operation, for this reason I want to avoid this since the largest part of devices yet have a file manager installed,
so I'm wondering if through the intent filter I have a way to perform this operation using an existing file manager already present in the device and eventually inviting the user to install one from the market if no file manager is found.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to get a file.  I don't know that it will suit your needs exactly, but it should put you on a path ...

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("text/csv");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getText(R.string.select_file)), 1);
```

Check here: http://www.blackmoonit.com/2010/02/handling-browse-for-folder-intents/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in this way the file manager allow me to select a file to open, I need that file manager allows me to choose a folder not a file

Comment: Pretty sure I called that out in my answer ;)  I don't know if what you're trying to do can be done without an in-app file manager or a file manager already installed on the device, but I was offering a clue ... you might have to try ;)

Comment: I have already used intent filter to select a file in the past, but  now I need to select a folder that the user can choose as destination to save files created by my app. Is enough that this operation could be performed by an already istalled file manager, if is missing a valid file manager in the user device I could invite the user to install it... Include a whole file manager in every app seems a really dirty procedure.

Comment: `Include a whole file manager in every app seems a really dirty procedure.`. Including a file browser in every program to pick files or folders is the way to go. You can make a file browser with little code.